# A dilemma for finding http URL path

Tags: java, url

I find my self in a dilemma for finding a way to retrieve the urlpath.
I want to retrieve the base url from a http url for example :

```
http://www.test.com/somepath/path1/
base url is : test.com/somepath/path1

http://www.test.com/somepath/path1/file1.html
base url is : test.com/somepath/path1

http://www.test.com/somepath/path1/path2
base url is : test.com/somepath/path1/path2
```

but in java by using URL object and using getHost() and getPath() and getFile() I will get the following result:

```
1.
host : www.test.com (correct)
path : /somepath/path1 (correct)
file : /somepath/path1 (it should be empty but its not!)
2.
host : www.test.com (correct)
path : /somepath/path1/file1.html (incorrect)
file : /somepath/path1/file1.html (it should be file1.html)
3.
host : www.test.com (correct)
path : /somepath/path1/path2 (correct)
file : /somepath/path1/path2 (it should be empty/null)
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: as I explained : URL.getHost() / getPath() / getFile()

Comment: Could you add the code to the question? It's easier to see what the issue is when we see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url object doesn't know if /path2 is a file or a directory, because if an url does not end with a "/", officially it's not a directory. You can add an additional check to cope with this problem. Split the url and check if the last part contains a "." as found for example in "index.html".

Code example

```
String[] urlSplt = urlStr.split("/");
if(urlSplt[urlSplt.length - 1].contains(".")){
    //URL is a file
} else{
    //url is not a file
}
```

Good luck!